# Prevent Visual Studio 2022 from debugging in Docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Since the Visual Studio 2022 17.5 update my builds have been taking ages - instead of ~10 seconds, I'm now waiting ~<s>10</s> 20 minutes or more.

If I look in the 'Container Tools' window I can see a `docker build` command being executed, and in the 'Background tasks' I see the message...

> Warming up Docker debugging for project [my startup project]

I think this feature (added in the 17.5 update) seems to be triggered by the presence of a DOCKERFILE in the project.

While it's true that this main project (and others in the solution) does contain a DOCKERFILE, my team don't run these locally; we only build the containers in our devops pipeline after local development.

Furthermore, the base image we use is `windowsservercore-ltsc2022`, which is not what I run locally, so it's incompatible with my local system anyway.

Can I turn off this feature?

---

**UPDATE**
Some additional points:

- This long build time only occurs after restarting Visual Studio.
- I have Docker Desktop installed but not running. (I've repeated the steps with Docker Desktop already running, and it makes no difference.)
- If I rename `DOCKERFILE` to, say, `_DOCKERFILE` then the problem goes away.
- The solution in question is .NET Framework.

**UPDATE 2**
Even after renaming `DOCKERFILE` to `_DOCKERFILE`, the first build after restarting Visual Studioo *still* attempts to debug in a container - I see this in the `Container Tools` window...

> 66>------- Started building project: [*name of my .NET Framework project*]
> 66>Container warmup in progress – waiting for this to complete. See the Container Tools output pane for details.

I had to cancel the build after 45 minutes because it still hadn't completed. There must be a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 7):

Removing the `bin` and `obj` folders and retrying worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The warm-up behavior can be disabled in the options dialog. Full details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build#project-warmup

Example for disabling for a single project:
[image]

Example for disabling Docker Desktop Checks:
[image]

As an aside, if you choose any launch profile other than Docker, warm-up shouldn't even be considered on the next VS launch. To change your launch profile click on the down arrow on the Debug button:
[image]

Comment: Hi Nathan, Could you please state explicitly which option I need to change? I've read that `Project warmup` section several times, and looked at all the VS options _many_ times, and I still don't see what I should change to prevent this happening.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, but this hasn't helped. Building the solution still takes around 20 minutes. I've added some additional information in the OP.

Comment: Thanks again Nathan, but those are the settings I have, and I use IIS/localhost development locally, not Docker. So why is it that if I build a project containing a DOCKERFILE, Visual Studio still attempts to download that base image and pack that container?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. What I've tired:
Clean machine configured as per the screen shots, ASP.Net Framework (not core) web project, Add Docker support, Open VS with Docker Desktop installed but not running.
If I don't have the Docker launch profile selected i don't see any output. If I do I only see:
= Checking for Container Prerequisites =
Verifying that Docker Desktop is installed...
Docker Desktop is installed.
= Verifying that Docker Desktop is running... =
Verifying that Docker Desktop is running...
Docker Desktop is not running.
--
Am i missing a step?

Comment: This has stopped happening - without any changes to the project/solution or Dockerfile, it simply stopped happening. My build times are now back to normal. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was fixed opening the `.csproj.user` and changing the ActiveDebugProfile from Docker to https

```
<ActiveDebugProfile>https</ActiveDebugProfile>
```

Comment: FYI: This should only be applicable to ASP.NET Core projects. I believe the original post was about an ASP.NET project.